# DynamoDB mapper save only one attribute in an item Java

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, getter-setter

I am getting a item record from my dynamodb table adding an attribute (userratings) and then saving it again like this:

```
 SongDatabaseMappingAdapter song = mapper.load(SongDatabaseMappingAdapter.class, params[0]);
            song.getUserRatings().add(userID + "-" + params[1] + "-" + sdf.format(date));
            mapper.save(song);
```

The problem is in my SongDatabaseMappingAdapter I have some extra getter setters that are being used to update the GUI, like this:

```
public Boolean getOneStarRating() {
        return onestarrating;
    }

    public void setOneStarRating(Boolean onestarrating) {

        this.onestarrating = onestarrating;
    }
```

I need them to be there but I don't want them to save to the attributes in my database but when I run my code to save the item is adding all the attributes which is every element in my getter/setter (Mapping Adapter) into the item so I end up with extra attributes (columns) like below (All of the star ratings below have been added but shouldn't be there):

```
UserRatings fiveStarRating fourStarRating oneStarRating
```

So basically I want to change my code so it is only saving the userratings attribute in the song item not all of the attributes. I was thinking of something like below, but I am not sure how to do it (the code below doesn't work)

```
  SongDatabaseMappingAdapter song = mapper.load(SongDatabaseMappingAdapter.class, params[0]);
                song.getUserRatings().add(userID + "-" + params[1] + "-" + sdf.format(date));
                mapper.save(song.setUserRatings());
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate the extra attributes with `@DynamoDBIgnore`. As per the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBIgnore):

> **DynamoDBIgnore**
>
> Indicates to the DynamoDBMapper instance that the associated property
>   should be ignored. When saving data to the table, the DynamoDBMapper
>   does not save this property to the table.